# Disable screen turn off

Tags: xorg, x-server, xmonad

I want to watch a movie with my laptop how I can disable with xmonad that it turn off the screen if vlc or some other app is running is running.
Is there some functions what I can used to prevent this?

Can I do there something with Xmonad or is it depending to my X?
Any ideas?

Comment: which program is inducing the black screen - most likely something like xscreensaver or some power manager. I have xfce4-power-manager - there I just switch to presentation mode.

Comment: It should come from my X server, but I want to know if I can do something with my xmonad configuration if write some code there.
I'll check this if know other way thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have these lines in my `~/.xinitrc` file:

```
# turn off Display Power Management Service (DPMS)
xset -dpms
setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0

# turn off black Screensaver
xset s off
```

This prevents the display from turning off during watching a movie (I'm also using XMonad).

Comment: But I think is better if I put this in a script and used if I need it because I think in the xinitrc is not the best place for it. If every time this dpms disabled is

Comment: How I can enable the default again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your screensaver to be paused only when you watch a movie you can use [xssproxy](https://github.com/timakro/xssproxy). It's available as a [debian package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/xssproxy) as well as a [NixOS package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/28629).